# proyecto wordpress no envia correo, falla conexion SMTP

Tags: wordpress, hosting, wordpress-plugin, smtp

Tengo un proyecto en worpress montado en el hosting `100webspace`. Sucede que estoy intentando enviar correos por el plugin `contact form 7` y `WP Mail SMTP by WPForms`. 
Le coloco los datos para el server host, mbox.100ws.com, para el puerto, 465 y el nombre de usuario y contraseña de servidor de correo. Cuando intento enviar un correo de prueba desde `WP Mail SMTP by WPForms` obtengo el siguiente error `Could not connect to the SMTP host`

Comment: Pues el error dice que los parámetros de conexión son incorrectos (lo más probable) o no es posible salir por el puerto 465

Comment: Lo hice a nivel local con el smtp de Google y funciono bien. Lo subi al hosting con la misma configuracion del SMTP de Google y me salio el mismo mensaje de `Could not connect to the SMTP host`

Comment: Entonces pasa que alguna regla en tu hosting no permite las conexiones salientes por esos puertos. Revísalo con tu proveedor.

Comment: Tal vez deberías usar otro proveedor como mailjet.